# PHP display data after values set as keys in looping rows of SQL data

Tags: php, sql

Have a table that uses values as keys on a row by row basis. The last column of the table should contain values not as keys, but as the values themselves. I could put this column before the columns with the values as keys, but it would be a sloppy-looking table.

```
if ($myquery = $mysqli->query ($sqlSelect)) {
  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myquery)){
    $tmp = array();
    foreach (array('device1', 'device2', 'device3', 'device4', 'device5') as $key) {
      if (!isset($tmp[$row[$key]])) $tmp[$row[$key]] = array();
      $tmp[$row[$key]][] = $key;
    }
    $result[$row['title'] . "</td><td>" . $row['title_code']] = $tmp;
  }

  $max = 0;
  foreach ($result as $data => $inputs) {
    $max = max($max, count($inputs));
  }
  foreach ($result as $data => $inputs) {
    print('<tr><td>' . $data . '</td>');
    foreach ($inputs as $input => $devices) {
      print('<td><strong>' . $input . ':</strong><br/>' . implode('<br/>', $devices) . '</td>');
    }
    // the following line makes blank cells to fill dead space
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max - count($inputs); ++$i) {
      print('<td></td>');
    }

    print('<td>' . $row['notes'] . '</td></tr>');
  }
}
```

How do I get the values ignorantly-noted as `$row['notes']` to display the values for the field after the columns that use values as keys?

The resulting table should look like this:

```
title   title_code header1 header2 header3 Notes
Title1  Code1      inputA: inputB:         data 
                   Device1 Device3 
Title2  Code2      inputA: inputB: inputC: data
                   Device1 Device2 Device3
Title3  Code3      inputB:                 data
                   Device1
```

For more on what this table looks like, see [PHP print SQL field names as array with corresponding values showing once per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522432/php-print-sql-field-names-as-array-with-corresponding-values-showing-once-per-ro)

Comment: I've added `$result[$row['notes']] = $note;` after the first `$result` declaration, and used `$note` instead of `$row['notes']`, but the data shows up on the next lines, not the same rows. Almost there...

Comment: Is there a way to use `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` to accomplish this?

Comment: Should I not use `$result` and declare different variables?